# Apple Bluetooth keyboard is not configureable via modprobe.d directory

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, apple

I have a MacBook Pro and installed Archlinux on it. I have read their article about [Apple Keyboards](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Apple_Keyboard), and managed to make the function key work properly (meaning pressing F5 actually triggers F5), fix some swapped keys using `isolayout` and would like to swap the opt and cmd key.

So I have create a file called `/etc/modprobe.d/apple_keyboard.conf`, and put the following content in it:

```
options hid_apple fnmode=2 isolayout=0 swap_opt_cmd=1
```

This works for the internal keyboard of the macbook, but I also have a apple bluetooth keyboard, for which these options don't seem to apply. Especially the opt and cmd key are not swapped for the bluetooth keyboard. I have no idea what I can check, so I would be thankful for any hint.

**UPDATE**:

Just realized that I have written `isolayout`  instead of `iso_layout`. If I change that, < and ^ key are switched on the internal keyboard. I don't have the bluetooth keyboard with me, but I'll update on monday to see if it is at least correct with the other keyboard. However, if this is the case I would need a way to differ between both keyboards...

**UPDATE**

The bluetooth keyboard is still not affected by the `iso_layout` setting...

**UPDATE**

I've been told to add the output of `dmesg`, after plugging the keyboard (I did this by turning it off and on again), and this is what appears:

```
[56929.073859] hid-generic 0005:004C:026C.000B: unknown main item tag 0x0
[56929.073921] input: Magic Keyboard with Numeric Keypad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8.3/1-8.3:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:11/0005:004C:026C.000B/input/input24
[56929.074084] hid-generic 0005:004C:026C.000B: input,hidraw2: BLUETOOTH HID v0.80 Keyboard [Magic Keyboard with Numeric Keypad] on 34:36:3b:ca:dd:71
```

Comment: Please edit your question with the lines that appear in `dmesg` after you plug in the bluetooth keyboard.

Comment: @dirkt Updated. Does look like the keyboard is not using `hid_apple` at all, right?

Comment: Yup, looks like a generic HID device. The kernel input layer can remap scan codes to key codes via ioctls, but there are no packaged command line tools. You can try the [udev hwdb](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Map_scancodes_to_keycodes) instead.

Comment: Hm, I see... Isn't there an easier way to make the bluetooth keyboard also use the hid-apple driver?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue when the bluetooth connection was loading `hid_generic` but the USB connection was loading the correct `hid_apple`.

What fixed for me was installing the patched `hid_apple` module from [free5lot/hid-apple-patched](https://github.com/free5lot/hid-apple-patched). Maintainers are frequently syncing upstream with the newest changes on the kernel. In my case installing the patched version on Ubuntu 20.04 with kernel `5.4.0-88-generic` fixed the issue and now both bluetooh and USB are using `hid_apple` so all the options you set on `/etc/modprobe.d/hid_apple.conf` such as `swap_opt_cmd` (the one I was struggling with) are working.

Below both the USB and Bluetooth outputs from `dmesg -w`. Both prefixed with `apple`, meaning that the patched `hid_apple` module loaded actually fixed the issue. Besides, the last one shows how it was loading before applying the patched version, using `hid-generic`.

```
[70447.039634] apple 0003:05AC:024F.0029: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Keychron Keychron K8] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input0
[70447.039919] apple 0003:05AC:024F.002A: Fn key not found (Apple Wireless Keyboard clone?), disabling Fn key handling
```

```
[70457.404925] input: Keychron K8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256/0005:05AC:024F.002B/input/input155
[70457.405245] apple 0005:05AC:024F.002B: input,hidraw2: BLUETOOTH HID v1.05 Keyboard [Keychron K8] on 48:45:20:82:6c:33
```

Before the installation of the patched module:

```
[69784.281885] input: Keychron K8 Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256/0005:05AC:024F.0028/input/input147
[69784.282213] input: Keychron K8 Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256/0005:05AC:024F.0028/input/input148
[69784.282345] input: Keychron K8 System Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256/0005:05AC:024F.0028/input/input149
[69784.282481] hid-generic 0005:05AC:024F.0028: input,hidraw2: BLUETOOTH HID v1.05 Keyboard [Keychron K8] on 48:45:20:82:6c:33
```

Comment: The hid_apple module included in Ubuntu 22.04 or later should work without having to install a third-party package.